# UIImageView Rotate Animation inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to rotate an UIImage view on selecting `row 0`. On selection that section needs to reload to add two more cells. This is where the animation fails to work. The imageview just transforms to the new position without performing the animation.

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                print(cell)
            }

            if displayCell {


                UIView.animate(withDuration:0.3, animations: {
                    cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0))
                })



                if indexPath.row != 0 {
                    swap(&indexArr[indexPath.row], &indexArr[0])
                    print(indexArr)
                }
            } else {

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
                })

            }

            displayCell = !displayCell

            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .none)
    }
```

Also that particular cell at row = 0, the content needs to be updated.
Here is a [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gx8pY0asBmaTlZTjZ4eVgyQjQ/view?usp=sharing) project:

Comment: what is it that is failing to work exactly?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need reload your `UITableView` sections after your animations is over

You also need **modify your cellForRow method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.rotateButtonImageView.isHidden =  indexPath.row != 0 || indexArr.count <= 2
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                if displayCell{
                    cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
                }else{
                    cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = .identity
                }
            }
            break
        default :
            cell.rotateButtonImageView.isHidden = true
            break

        }
        cell.indexLabel.text = indexArr[indexPath.row].0

        return cell

    }
```

**Use this code for your `didSelectRowAt` method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print(cell)
    }

    if displayCell {

        cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0))
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .automatic)
        })

        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            swap(&indexArr[indexPath.row], &indexArr[0])
            print(indexArr)
        }
    } else {

        cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.rotateButtonImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * .pi) / 180.0)
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: .automatic)
        })

    }

    displayCell = !displayCell
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your input but I tried this and it didn't help

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan my answer was updated again, i will post gif with results